# convert HD (1080p) mov files to mpg or others

Tags: conversion, ps3

I want to convert a HD MOV file in a format that is playable on the PS3.
I tried different tools but none of them worked correctly.

after converting the resolution is awful or the conversion stopped after a few minutes or didn't even start.

Does anyone know a tool that really works and keeps the resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely get [MKV2VOB](http://www.mkv2vob.com/showthread.php?tid=1) it is the best converter I have used for MKV files to playstation 3. It converts them in under 5 minutes, literally! And it will work exactly with the same quality as you got it.

Use the x264 high bitrate option for maximum quality, it also carries the same audio source, so it will contain the dolby digital/dts audio and will keep the same resolution.

Answer (score 1):

**[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)**.

It's an open source, GPL-licensed, multi-threaded video format transcoder, and it's available for Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X.

Works great for all of your <s>illegal</s> legal video conversion needs. [Get it now](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php).

Comment: I tried handbrake but it didn't work for me. Actually I can't remember why right now. I have to try again. Any other transcoder suggestions?

Comment: @user575376: What about it didn't work? I've never had a problem using this software, and it's highly recommended by every review I've ever seen. If you don't get good results with any of the software you've tried, it's more than likely a problem with the video file you're trying to convert rather than the converter tool.

Comment: you could be right. I will get the current release of handbrake and try it again. maybe it is the file. i will download a hd movie trailer in mov format and try this also.

Answer (score 0):

PS3 support MP4 (MPEG -4) or H.264.If you want convert a HD MOV to it,this [PS3 Video Converter](http://www.aneesoft.com/win-ps3-video-converter.html) can help you.It can change the resolution for you need.